# three.js OribtControls tilt camera by some angle

Tags: camera, three.js

THREE.OrbitControls places a camera the way it's frustum near plane is orthogonal to the observed point, so the default implementation gives me top view. What I need is a bit tilted camera, so the view is not completely from top. Pretty much like any strategy game out there, your camera is slightly rotated to give you more detail, instead of just giving you purely top view.

THREE.OrbitControls controls camera rotation through quaternion (x,y,z,w) where x,y,z is a vector from (0,0,0) to center of camera, and w is rotation angle around that vector. Now what is the needed translation to the (x,y,z) vector to allow to tilt the camera by a given angle?